# Adding (time-dependent) noise

Tags: random

The *Mathematica* documentation center provides an example of how to add noise to a process: [White Noise Process](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhiteNoiseProcess.html).

```
\[ScriptCapitalP] = TransformedProcess[
             Cos[t/8] + noise[t], 
             noise \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[UniformDistribution[{-1/5, 1/5}]],
             t];

data = RandomFunction[\[ScriptCapitalP], {0, 200}];
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm also able to do the same with Gaussian noise, in which case I use `NormalDistribution[0, 1]` instead of `UniformDistribution[{-1/5, 1/5}]`.

I have now two problems:

- The first one is that I want the standard derivation to be a function of time, so `NormalDistribution[0, f[t]]`, but this doesn't work.
- The second problem is that I always get nothing when I choose the variance to be zero, which should effectively correspond to no noise.

Can someone help?

Comment: When I have no noise, so zero mean and zero variance, I should get the original process back again, which I don't. Was only curious about that.

Comment: Now I see, sorry I wasn't paying close enough attention

Comment: Mathematica can't handle the (singular) case of $\sigma\rightarrow 0$. Try `PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0], x]`, which throws the error `NormalDistribution::posprm: "Parameter 0 at position 2 in NormalDistribution[0,0] is expected to be positive."`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nice thing about `NormalDistribution` is that it scales:

```
In[104]:= TransformedDistribution[sigma*u, 
 u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]

Out[104]= NormalDistribution[0, Abs[sigma]]
```

So `NormalDistribution[0, f[t]]` is equivalent to `f[t]*NormalDistribution[0,1]`, assuming `f[t]` is positive.

Then just adjust the transformation in `TransformedProcess`:

```
proc = 
  TransformedProcess[Cos[t/8] + Sqrt[t]*noise[t], 
  noise \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 1]],t];
data = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 200}];
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: with the adjusted noise]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I increase the number of points? When I'm using RandomFunction[proc,{0,200,0.2}] I always get an error...

Comment: That is bc WhiteNoiseProcess in M is a discrete time process and RandomFunction can only output sample on integers. What you can do is to specify the length of the sample and then use TimeSeriesRescale to rescale time stamps to the MinimumTimeIncrement of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any experience with `TransformedProcess` or `RandomFunction`, but coulddn't you just make your own noise and add it to the data?

```
data = Cos[#/8] + 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, # .001 + .05]] & /@ 
   Range[0, 200];
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to implement this later! :-)